# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, infinispan

I am getting the following error when I build my project, I tried various other StackOverflow answers but all in vain.

Also tried to exclude `logback` from all the dependencies,

```
configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
}
```

And the above does solve the problem but gives another error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter`, seems like it is using `logback` some place else and hence `logback` cannot be excluded from all the dependencies. Any suggestion on how to get rid of the issue would be really valuable. Thanks.

**Error log**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a
> Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove
> Logback or the competing implementation (class
> org.jboss.slf4j.JBossLoggerFactory loaded from
> file:/C:/Users/idnpga/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.infinispan/infinispan-embedded/9.1.7.Final/6b94fd0e5872b8ce90ab35531afe90d1efaf36f0/infinispan-embedded-9.1.7.Final.jar).
> If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
> prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
> org.jboss.slf4j.JBossLoggerFactory    at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:696)
> at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:596)    at
> org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:284)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:104)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:232)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:213)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:47)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> ... 81 more

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf') {
            exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy'
        }
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
        implementation('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-explorer')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ip')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-stream')
        implementation('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-xml')
        implementation('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security') {
            exclude group: 'org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl'
        }
        implementation ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core') {
            exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson'
        }
        
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '3.0.4.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix', version: '2.1.5.RELEASE'

        implementation 'org.infinispan:infinispan-spring-boot-starter-parent:14.0.0.Dev01'
        implementation 'org.infinispan:spring-boot-starter-infinispan-autoconfigure:1.0.0'
        implementation('org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded:9.1.7.Final')

        implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.9'
        testImplementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.9'
        implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.9'
        testImplementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.9'


        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage',  module : 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
        testImplementation('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test')
        testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-wiremock:3.1.1")
        
        testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier") {
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot',  module : 'spring-boot-starter-test'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Infispan includes slf4j as a dependency in the jar. So I suspect you need to remove the infispan-embedded dependency as that includes a conflucting one. Remove your logback dependencies as those are already including in Spring Boot.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the logback dependencies but not sure how slf4j can be excluded from infinispan dependency. I tried this -> `implementation('org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded:9.1.7.Final') { exclude group: 'org.jboss.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-jboss-logging'}` but this does not exclude the `slf4j` dependency.

Comment: It won't as it is included in the jar file it isn't a dependency but a repacked jar inside that dependency. You should find another dependency for infinispan that doesn't have this (maybe a collection of jars instead of the embedded one).

Comment: Ok got it, will look it up. Thanks!